# C++ constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Class MainWindow

In one of method of the Class I call another Class ("test") in the way

```
 test = new Test (this,app_language,&filename2);
```

Test Class is :

```
Test::Test(QWidget *parent,QString lang, QString *filename)
: QDialog(parent)
, ui(new Ui::Report)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

One of method Test Class I change value of filename in this way

```
void Test::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  filename = "TEST CLASS";
}
```

but the compiler reutrns error because filename was not declared

My question is:

How to use filename in methods of Test Class and return new value to MainWindow Class?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Could you be more clear?

Comment: From MainWindow Class I call new Class "Test" and  in constructor of "Test" class I send pointer to filename and in Test Class I change value of filename. After changing I would like to have new value in MainWindow Class. This way I call new Class Test = new Test(this,app_language,&filename2);

Comment: Your code shows you doing nothing with `filename`.  So your explanation doesn't match with what you're showing us.

Comment: I would like to change Qstring *filename value but I do not know how to make visable the variable in the methods class "Test"

Comment: @Mystery Create a member variable and store the value.  What is the difficulty there?

Comment: Don't pass around pointers to strings, make it a QString Q_PROPERTY/member in Test and a signal like "filenameChanged()" to notify the main window of changes.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Do you think they are going to understand this when they dont even understand why it is the compiler is saying filename is not declared when its clearly not declared?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to return to MainWindow Class new value filename2. In constructor I pass pointer to filename2.

Answer (score 0):

In your class you shall add a member like this:

```
class Test
{
// ...
    void setFilename( const QString& aFilename ) { m_Filename = aFilename; }
    QString filename() const { return m_Filename; }

private:
    QString m_Filename;
};
```

and in all the function pass a `const QString&` instead of a `QString*`. After this your code will compile:

```
void Test::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    m_Filename = "TEST CLASS";
}
```

Comment: I need return the new value into MainWindow Class.

Comment: What kind of new value ?

Comment: I have in MainWindow Class QString filename2 and in Test Class I would like to change the value and send it back

Comment: `QString` is not big class so why not just write a setter and a getter function for this purpose ? I updated my answer with your request.

Comment: test = new Test(this,app_language,&filename2);
        test->setModal(true);
        test->exec(); If the new windows is open the filename2 can be changed many times (There are many actions,methods etc) - in this time the mainwondow class waits.  I have 2 ways in destructor pass new value of filename2 or work on  pointer to filename2.

Comment: In this case just dereferece the `QString*`, in the following way: `*filename = "TEST CLASS";`, and it will be compilable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to this question. The first one is easy and answers the question directly and quickly but IS NOT RECOMMENDED.

I am reluctant to even show you the first answer because it's bad design and can lead to problems later on but I decided to show this solution anyway because it illustrate the concept of variable scope and why you could not access data from one function that was passed in via a different function.

---

The reason you are getting that compiler error is because function parameters only have scope in the function they are defined in.

What this means is that, in the constructor for `Test`, the three parameters (`QWidget *parent`, `QString lang` and `QString *filename`) are only accessible inside the constructor body. Once program control exits the constructor, these parameters are destroyed and you can no longer access their data.

If you wish to access data in another function, as you clearly wish to do in `void Test::on_pushButton_clicked()`, you need to store the values in a data member.

In your code, the value of `parent` is passed on to the constructor of `QDialog` and stored there so you don't have to do anything special with that one but you are not storing the values of `lang` or `filename` so you lose access to those.

To make your code work in with its current design, you need to make the following modification:

```
class Test : public QDialog{
    // ...

private:
    QString language;
    QString *filename;
};

Test::Test(QWidget *parent, QString app_language, QString *f)
: QDialog(parent), language(app_language), filename(f), ui(new Ui::Report)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void Test::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    *filename = "TEST CLASS";
}
```

The reason this first answer is a VERY BAD IDEA is because you should always aim to keep your code as [loosely coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) as you can, and the way you were solving your problem creates a very tight coupling between your `MainWindow` class and your `Test` class.

---

This second answer shows you a much better way of solving your problem with much looser coupling between the classes. In fact, the `Test` class has absolutely no knowledge or connection with the `MainWindow` class in the following code.

```
class Test : public QDialog{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test(QWidget *parent, QString app_language);

    // ...

signals:
    void filenameChanged(QString const &newFilename);

    // ...

private:
    QString language;
};

Test::Test(QWidget *parent, QString app_language)
: QDialog(parent), language(app_language), ui(new Ui::Report)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void Test::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    emit filenameChanged("TEST CLASS");
}

// MAIN WINDOW CLASS

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // ...

    void showTestClass();

public slots:
    void filename2Changed(QString const &newFilename);

private:
    QString filename2;
    QString app_language;
};

void MainWindow::showTestClass()
{
    Test test(this, app_language);
    connect(&test, &Test::filenameChanged, this, &MainWindow::filename2Changed);
    test.exec();
}

void MainWindow::filename2Changed(QString const &newFilename)
{
    filename2 = newFilename;
}
```

The Signals-Slots mechanism is a core feature of Qt and is a convenient example of setting up Message Coupling.